# No internet connection: method call into another dll takes more than 15 seconds

Tags: .net, network-programming, delayed-execution

I'm facing the following issue I just can't explain:

I have two dlls (DllA and DllB). When I call the first time from DllA into Dllb "ObjectFromB.aMethod()" everything works fine and fast. However, when I call another method from DllA in DllB "ObjectFromB.anotherMethod()" it takes more than 15 seconds!! I can't figure out why... Except the method/signature everything is exactly the same (same thread, same objects, same assemblies, same call stack (until there) and then two only distinct methods/signatures (into the same object)).

Important: The issue happens only if I don't have internet connection!

Comment: Is the problem when you have no network connection at all or when you have a network connection but can't connect to the internet?

Comment: Are both DLL's your? do you have access to the source?

Comment: Yes, I have access to the source. I have network connection but can't connect to the internet.

Comment: Have you steped through the code and do you know what call within the method is taking a long time?

Comment: Yes, if I call anotherMethod() (I know the name of the method) I trace a message before the call and in the method itself. The delay is more the 15".

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler or a sniffer (wireshark etc..) to find out what the application is connecting to in the hope it might shed some light on what is causing the delay or timeout.

Comment: i sugested fiddler because it simple to use if the request is a HTTP call.

Comment: I'll try Wireshark and Fiddler and get back asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason of my issue:

Some DLLs I've been using are signed binaries. anotherMethod() contains a type in its signature from another DLL (DllC). Unfortunatley it couldn't authenticate this DLL because of the missing Internet connection. A solution/workaround can be found here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936707/en-us